# C# Convert Bitmap to indexed colour format

Tags: c#, .net, windows, gdi+

How can I convert a 24-bit colour `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to an indexed (256-colour) format? I'm having trouble working out how to calculate the palette. I can iterate over the pixels and use an `int[]` to contain the various colours but the problem comes when there are more than 256 colours. Is there a way to convert to an indexed format and extract a 256-colour palette from an `Bitmap` ?

Comment: You should first choose what kind of indexed bitmap do you require.  Do you have <= 256 colors to start with?

Answer (score 5):

Using the Bitmap Clone Method you can directly convert the Source Image to a 256 color Palette Indexed image like this:

```
Bitmap Result = Source.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, Source.Width, Source.Height), PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

Then if you want access the Palette Colors, just use the `Result.Palette.Entries` property.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge earlier. It's possible to solve using GDI+ in .Net.

This article helped me a lot (including samples): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa479306

For best quality use "Octree-based Quantization".

Answer (score 1):

WPF has access to the Windows Imaging Component, from there you can use a [FormatConvertedBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap.aspx) to convert the image to a new pixel format. WIC is much much faster than the System.Drawing methods on Vista and 7 and will allow you a lot more options.

Answer (score 0):

This is not built-in but you can either use external .NET libraries for this or shell out to the console to invoke ImageMagic.

Comment: Actually it is available in WPF via [FormatConvertedBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Some reading material to get you started.

- Graphic Gems I pp. 287-293, "A Simple Method for Color Quantization: Octree Quantization"
- B. Kurz. Optimal Color Quantization for Color Displays. Proceedings of the IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, 1983, pp. 217-224.
- Graphic Gems II pp. 116-125, "Efficient Inverse Color Map Computation"

This paper describes an efficient technique to map actual colors to a reduced color map, selected by some other technique described in the other papers.

- Graphic Gems II pp. 126-133, "Efficient Statistical Computations for Optimal Color Quantization"
- Xiaolin Wu. Color Quantization by Dynamic Programming and Principal Analysis. ACM Transactions on Graphics, Vol. 11, No. 4, October 1992, pp 348-372.